# Referencing Two-Word Variables in Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm attempting to get some data from an app called "Timing", which is local to my computer, and post it to a URL to notify a webhook, from which some process automation will occur.

[According to the Applescript integration with Timing,](https://timingapp.com/help/applescript#class_time_summary__Timing_Helper_Suite)

There is a `time summary` object that's returned from a command which I've successfully executed. When displayed as an alert, that data looks like this:

> `Can't get |times per project| of {id:5C6CD8C8-357F-4EE7-890C-5946DC03BBB9", overall total:1.18092493622303E+4, times per project:{Maintenance:81.091759443283, Youtube:4820.38001298904, |self improvement effors|:876.930474758148, Homework:2383.20326805115, |(no project)|:3647.64384698868}, overall total without tasks:1.18092493622303E+4, productivity score:0.388005592511, times per project without tasks:{Maintenance:81.091759443283, Youtube:4820.38001298904, |self improvement efforts|:876.930474758148, Homework:2383.20326805115, |(no project)|:3647.64384698868}, class:time summary}.`

As you can see, (above), there is a property called `productivity score`, which is two words.

When attempting to get this datapoint from the object (which I will use to notify the webhook:)

```
set newnewVar to productivity score of newvar
display alert newvar
```

Obviously this wont work, because the variable name is two words. I've tried surrounding the name in quotes and surround it with other characters, but nothing seems to work, and [the documentation for getting specific properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_variables.html) only has examples with variables with one word.

What's the solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you notice in the linked article it states "Note that scripts addressing Timing should begin with `tell application "TimingHelper"`, not with `tell application "Timing"`" and are you doing that? In other words, to get the _value_ of `productivity score` are you doing that within a `tell application "TimingHelper"` _block_?

Comment: Yes I am- the code to get that object is actually copied from the site, and works well. It's just a matter of getting variables with two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppleScript, *user-defined* variables cannot generally have spaces.  Typically they start with a letter or underscore, and then can contain only letters, numbers, or underscores. A user-defined variable can only contain spaces if it is contained within vertical pipes. So all of the following are valid variable forms: `alphaUnit`, `slideRow3`, `_tempItem`, `|my variable|`, `left_hand_vector`

However, any application or script that creates and uses a scripting definition can create commands and classes and properties that have multi-word names. For instance, if you look at the System Events app, you'll see that the Disk-Folder-File Suite has a class named `disk item` with properties like `creation date`. The reason this works is that these multi-word names are actually represented by a numeric (four-char) code: `disk item` is actually `'ditm'` and `creation date` is `'ascd'`. You often see these codes pop up in error strings like so:

> `"cannot make class ≪ditm≫ into..."`

Make sure you have the scope right to invoke the dictionary — i.e. be within a `tell` block for the app or script that invokes the scripting dictionary — and the multi-word names should 'just work'. After compiling, you'll see them highlighted in a purple color that's just a bit different from the red of uncompiled text. You do not need to enclose dictionary terms in vertical pipes; if you do, they will be treated as user-defined variables and lose their special scripting purposes.

Comment: You said "In AppleScript, user-defined variables cannot have spaces. They must start with a letter and contain only letters and numbers." and technically that is not true because a user-defined variable can start with an `_`, and that not a letter. Also, AppleScript provides a loophole to the rules: identifiers whose first and last characters are vertical bars `|` can contain any characters. The leading and trailing vertical bars are not considered part of the identifier. Meaning a user-defined variable can be anything and with spaces when placed between vertical bars `|`.

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry; forgot about the underscores and the pipes. But still...